# SLES YUM repo not listing RPMs

Tags: yum, sles

I created a SLES yum repository following this [link](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/06/opensuse-create-your-own-software-repository-1/)

Used the `createrepo` command, and got this folder structure:

```
/srv/www/htdocs/repo/RPMS/ -
                          - /OL
                          - /SLES
                          - /Third-Party/ -
                                   - a.rpm b.rpm c.rpm
                          -/repodata  
                                   - filelists.xml.gz other.xml.gz primary.xml.gz repomd.xml repomd.xml.asc repomd.xml.key
```

Everything is fine, and i was able to connect the repository locally, and from different machine as well (using http)

The problem is, if i try to search for an RPM in client machine, it does not list it. I am using SLES11 SP3.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got the answer.
I had wrongly run a createrepo command.

`createrepo` should be run, under each sub-folder where the RPMs exists.

Since my RPMs were inside Third-Party/ i run it like this:

```
sles11SP3-yast:/srv/www/htdocs/repo/RPMS # createrepo /srv/www/htdocs/repo/RPMS/Third-Party/
Spawning worker 0 with 4 pkgs
Workers Finished
Gathering worker results

Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
```

And once directly under the repo directory.

```
sles11SP3-yast:/srv/www/htdocs/repo # createrepo .
Spawning worker 0 with 4 pkgs
Workers Finished
Gathering worker results

Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
```